# Tensorflow Lite GPUdelegate gives "Dimensions are not BHWC" error for the last layer. But the layer appears to be BHWC like every other layers to me

Tags: android, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to implement a YOLO detector on android. I followed the demo code provided by tensorflow. The model runs fine on CPU or with NNAPI. However, when I try to run it with GPU, the program crashes and debugger gives out the following error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to apply delegate: GpuDelegate Prepare: Dimensions are not BHWCNode number 23 (GpuDelegate) failed to prepare.
```

The final layer of the model looks like `self.conv9 = layers.Conv2D(425, (1,1), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='conv_9', use_bias=False)`

The model runs perfectly fine on PC with either CPU or GPU.